# Excel - Copy only text part of the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to excel and am figuring out how to do this since last hour. I have a data in column B like

```
1. e4
1. ... e5
21. Nf6
21. ... Nf3
```

and want to extract it to column C like

```
1
1
21
21
```

i.e to copy only the integer part of the cell. Please note that 3 in Nf3 should not be copied, only the integer part before dot. I prefer not to use VBA script for this as I've never done it. If it can't be done with excel formulas, then please guide me how to do it with VBA.

Since the integer part is maximum of 2 digits, I'm thinking to extract the first 3 characters of the cell using `=LEFT(B1,3)`and then extracting the integer part.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An extra column is not necessary (nor any formula). Select the column, Text to Columns with `.` (only) as the delimiter and in Step 3 of 3 select all but the first column and check `Do not import column (skip)`. Will probably return General format (numbers as numbers) but alternatives are available.

But work on a copy if you wish to retain the source data.